# One CSS Class Dependent on Another

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I know this is a simple question.

If I two css classes:

```
.cssclass1 { ...some element .... }
.cssclass2 { ...some element .... }
```

and I want to use them in an input field:

```
<input type="text" class="cssclass1 cssclass2" />
```

how can I chain it so cssclass2 only renders if it's in the same element as cssclass1?

Comment: For the record - and I'm just being pedantic here - these are HTML classes, not CSS classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a selector written like this:

```
.cssclass1.cssclass2 { ... }
```

... you'll be able to set up a list of rules that will only be applied if an element has BOTH classes.

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS:

```
.cssclass2 {
  display: none;
}

.cssclass2.cssclass1 {
  display: block;
}
```

SCSS:

```
.cssclass2 {
  display: none;

  &.cssclass1 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
.cssclass1.cssclass2 { ...some element .... }
```

Comment: This would select an .cssclass2 element that is a descendent of a .cssclass1 element.

Answer (score 0):

```
.cssclass1.cssclass2 {
    //...
}
```

does exactly what you wanted to do.

For your record, this:

```
#foo.bar
```

selects the tag which has foo as id and bar as class. The first one solves your actual problem, but it doesn't hurt to know about the second one too.